# How to avoid bullet points and use a longer sentence instead?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

I can do many things:

- write with a pen while sitting
- smuggle milk through border crossings
- repent for thy sins with my sins

I would like to say what I have said above without using bullet points but I am not sure how to do it. Here is my take (please suggest something better):

I can do many things; one, write with a pen while sitting; two, smuggle milk through border crossings; three, repent for thy sins with my sins.

Comment: I can do many things: write with a pen while sitting, smuggle milk through border crossings, repent for thy sins with my sins.

Comment: Or: "Among the many things I can do are to write with a pen while sitting, to smuggle milk through border crossings, anf to repent for thy sins with my sins."

Answer (score 1):

I can do many things, such as write with a pen while sitting, smuggle milk through border crossings, and repent for thy sins with my sins.

Answer (score -5):

Never use bullet points. And never write long sentences. Write short sentences.

> I can do many things. I can write with a pen while sitting. I can
>   smuggle milk through border crossings, but not in to Australia. I can
>   repent for thy sins with my sins. Those are three of the things I can
>   do. I can do many things.

Just write how you would speak. It's impossible to speak long sentences. See Winston Churchill for how to write **slightly** longer sentences. (Forget commas, etc - just write properly.) But never write long sentences.

Comment: Why not? Bullet points can be much easier to read than a long list of things. Of course, there are times when you shouldn't use bullet points, but why the blanket prohibition?

Comment: For example, the following sentence is clearest when bulleted: *"What you need to bring on the expedition is long underwear, gloves, heavy socks, a heavy jacket, a windbreaker, a sun visor, a backpack, food, a water bottle, sunglasses, sunblock, a headlamp, skis, ski poles, a fifty-foot rope, a helmet, mountaineering boots, crampons, a sleeping bag, and a personal jet pack."